# Алгоритм Тарьяна поиска LCA

Tags: алгоритм

Пытаюсь разобрать алгоритм с описанием по [ссылке](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_LCA_%D0%B7%D0%B0_O(1)_%D0%B2_%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD).
Никак не могу понять, откуда следует корректность этого утверждения: *«Заметим, что при фиксированном v каждый из предков вершины v порождает некоторый класс вершин u, для которых он является ответом, в этом классе содержатся все вершины, которые находятся "слева" от этого предка.»*.

Ведь для любой вершины X, например, если взять её самого левого и самого правого потомков, то для них вершина X будет считаться наименьшим общим предком? Но это явно не то, что хотят сказать в алгоритме.

Что имеется в виду?